# sending push notification to Iphone using FCM

Tags: push, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification to iPhone using FCM but notification is not received on my phone. Is there any issue in request json? please help me.
my request json is

```
{ "notification":{"aps": {"alert": "Hello","badge": 1,"sound ": "default "},"pushtype": "", "message": "Hello"} ,"to" : "c6IJyzv8LiY:APA91bHE1g-51dWnh_ofus0nUfVGwWQBV8zOp5fn9VcQe5GLL6gqLUCQQv1RUnYvQ0MP7Q5bKwgG1_8Uuudf67HV4hU1N-3U4u4uRVpdXw3QrivE8ONxjAAfcbn5cIUzu3B6FbHR8EkG"}
```

and my response json is:

```
{\"multicast_id\":5810493506209108338,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1473238399084785%fc69f82ff9fd7ecd\"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed my problem, correct request json is:

```
{
    "notification ": {
        "title": "some title",
        "text": "some text"
    },
    "to": "XjV2kOqh1yXNkJsQop17RlwSwT4jZpuAu-...",
    "priority": "high"
}
```